# Slideshare presentation on Jframe

Tags: java, api, swing, powerpoint

Is it possible to view a slideshow of slideshare.com in a container of a JFrame in Java?

If yes, is the official API allows it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your best bet would be to try and leverage a browser component, given that's how Slideshare is designed to operate.

Check out the [DJ Native Swing Project](http://djproject.sourceforge.net/ns/index.html) which gives access to embeddable browser components (IE or Mozilla), Flash player and other goodies.

With this library, I'd probably use its JWebBrowser component to display the Slideshare widget that way. Although could try using the Flashplayer component too.

Answer (score 1):

POI is a common API that is used for accessing PowerPoint files.  Although, I don't think it provides easy exact display of the files. (There is usually just one official API for anything in Java).